# Как изменить ЧПУ на WordPress на нестандартный вид?

Tags: wordpress, чпу

В связи с миграцией сайта с 20к статьями на WP пришла необходимость изменить структуру url записей.
Сейчас есть site.ru/news/2315 так WP выводит без проблем, но нужно вывести так:
site.ru/news.php?id=2315 (цифра в конце - это не id поста, а url записи, а news - категория).
Как ни мучался не выходит... 301 редирект не рассматривается.

Comment: Для начала стоит понять, что `news.php?id=2315 ` это **не** ЧПУ. А потом всё же рассмотреть 301.

Comment: пускай не ЧПУ, а url записи, но 301 вот никак не рассматривается, увы.